# deploy web application on 8080 port

Tags: web-applications, dns, hosting

I created a web application using eclipse tomcat and mysql.
I would access my website on 'localhost:8080/HotelPromo'
Then I got a no-ip account and got a domain hotelpromo.no-ip.biz, and in no-ip this is pointing to my IP address(which I can ping).

I thought I would be able to access my web application using hotelpromo.no-ip.biz:8080/HotelPromo, but it's not working.

Is it because I'm trying to use the port 8080? If yes, where and How should I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with the port. Make sure it's open on your router. You can check if the port is open on this site: https://www.site24x7.com/port-test.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know weather my suggested answer is going to solve this problem or not(it might), but it might be helpful to you

---

Accessing **hotelpromo.no-ip.biz** instead of **hotelpromo.no-ip.biz:8080/HotelPromo**

1. Open server.xml 
    (ProjectExplorer|Navigator > Servers > Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config - Servers > server.xml)
2. Accessing **localhost/HotelPromo** instead **localhost:8080/HotelPromo**

   change

   `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

   to

   `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`
3. Now, accessing **localhost** instead **localhost/HotelPromo**

   change

   `<Context docBase="HotelPromo" path="/HotelPromo" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HotelPromo"/>`

   to

   `<Context docBase="HotelPromo" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HotelPromo"/>`

---

**NOTE:**
You can replace the *localhost* with *hotelpromo.no-ip.biz* when accessing through web

**Image Links**

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYbF8.jpg)

[step 2 and 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAsnN.jpg)

Comment: I was able to redirect to port 80 in my no-ip account. And also, my port 8080 was open but I had upgraded the OS and my IP had changed so it wasn't working..now it's fine